# NHibernate spatial geometry type become NULL is line contains only two points with same coordinates

Tags: nhibernate, geometry, geospatial, fluent

I have such class:

```
public class Edge
{
    public virtual Guid IDEdge { get; set; }
    public virtual Node Source { get; set; }
    public virtual Node Target { get; set; }
    public virtual double Length { get; set; }
    public virtual byte Car { get; set; }
    public virtual byte CarReverse { get; set; }
    public virtual IGeometry Geometry { get; set; }
}
```

...and fluent mapping:

```
public class EdgeMap : ClassMap<Edge>
{
    public EdgeMap()
    {
        Table("Edges");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.IDEdge).GeneratedBy.GuidComb().Column("IDEdge");
        References(x => x.Source).Column("Source");
        References(x => x.Target).Column("Target");
        Map(x => x.Length).Not.Nullable().Column("Length");
        Map(x => x.Car).Not.Nullable().Column("Car");
        Map(x => x.CarReverse).Not.Nullable().Column("CarReverse");
        Map(x => x.Geometry).CustomType<MsSql2008GeometryType>().Not.Nullable().Column("Geom");
    }
}
```

I tried to insert edge with geometry:

```
LINESTRING(37.2686 55.739,37.2686 55.739)
```

(two points with same coordinates)

I have got:

```
not-null property references a null or transient value Edge.Geometry
```

Somewhere instance of Geometry class has been lost. Edge inserts successfully if line contains different points.

Answer (score 0):

There is a restriction in SQL Server: A LineString must have at least two distinct points. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895372.aspx

NHibernate.Spatial currently is not throwing a proper exception for cases like this.